# In conversation, how common is it to use the structure "ne ... pas ... ne ... que" instead of "ne ... pas ... que"?

Tags: négation, constructions

> Les garçons **ne** devraient **pas** avoir **que** la peau sur les os.

When I say this in conversation, for instance, I see no other way to phrase the sentence than with "ne ... pas ... que". I mean, when "pas" and "que" are placed side by side or close to each other.

However, when "pas" and "que" are placed quite far apart, in spontaneous speech I sometimes find myself inserting the second "ne" like this:

> Les garçons **ne** sont **pas** faits pour **n**’avoir **que** la peau sur les os.

{Instead of}:

> Les garçons **ne** sont **pas** faits pour avoir **que** la peau sur les os.

It's not just me, but I sometimes hear French speakers around me use two "ne"s in a similar fashion, too. In conversation, how common is it to use this construction?

Comment: In hindsight, I should have phrased my question differently to better reflect the point that I truly wanted to ask about.

Answer (score 5):

The first form is the expected one:

> Les garçons **ne** sont **pas** faits pour **n**’avoir **que** la peau sur les os.

Unlike in you first sentence, there are two independent negations here: *ne pas* and *ne que* as show:

> Les garçons **ne** sont **pas** faits pour avoir la peau sur les os.
>
> Les garçons sont faits pour **n**’avoir **que** la peau sur les os.

Of course, in spoken French, both ***ne*** are often dropped leading to:

> Les garçons **sont** pas faits pour **avoir** que la peau sur les os.

Your last sentence contains a partial drop, which might be possible too.